# Spring Integration HttpGateway как настроить

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, messaging, spring-integration

Вот, что у меня получилось:

```
@Bean
    public MessageChannel messageChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Http.inboundGateway("https://complimentr.com/api"))
                .channel("messageChannel")
                .get();
    }
```

Я хочу, чтобы он делал запрос по этому урлу, и отправлял ответы в канал `messageChannel`. Но когда я запускаю программу, ничего не происходит!

Еще я хотела установить для него poller , но вот, что получиолсь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернетах совсем мало информаии про dsl, - все в xml

Как мне это поправить?

Answer (score 1):

`Http.inboundGateway` о входящих запросах. Смотри на него как на `@Controller`. Если ты хочешь отправлять запросы на URL, тогда нужно смотреть на `Http.outboundGateway` - думай о нем как о `RestTemplate`. Смотри доки: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/http.html#http